# Configuration x86_64-pc-msys not supported

Tags: gcc

I'm trying to build GCC 10.1 on my 64bit Windows 10 PC via `msys2` but I get this strange error that I don't understand. I didn't set the 3 switches: `--host`, `--build` and `--target` when I `./configure`d the GCC. So GCC picked these:

```
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-msys
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-msys
checking target system type... x86_64-pc-msys
```

I had provided all the required dependencies also updated the `msys2`: `pacman -Syuu`

```
checking if mkdir takes one argument... no
*** Configuration x86_64-pc-msys not supported
make[2]: *** [Makefile:4443: configure-stage1-gcc] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/c/gcc'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:25627: stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/c/gcc'
make: *** [Makefile:1001: all] Error 2
```

Comment: Try compiling it from the MinGW64 shell.